# HTML: How to change the width of input field based on container size

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have one Asp.net form in that I have two took  Containers. In one container I have inserted some paragraph values and in other container i have put Registration page element.

No my registration page has labels and textfields. I want to align textfield to right of the label when page width is greater than 1024 and if page size is less than 1024 then i want that text field below to the label.

How to make change in css for that. Please help to resolve this.
I am uploading the image so that you can better understand me.

[image: Problem with webpage in smartphone browser]

Here you can see when I open my website to my mobile it shows me like this. I just want to set Input Field below the Labels when screen size is less than 1024.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @media to adjust to different screen widths:

```
@media (min-width:1025px){
    input{
        display:inline-block;
    }
}
@media (max-width:1024px){
    input{
        display:block;
    }
}

<label for="name">Name:</label><input type="text" name="name"/>
```

## <kbd>[JSFiddle Demo (Resize result pane)](http://jsfiddle.net/qP8DY/2591/)</kbd>

Comment: Hey if I apply @media query to labels it will not work. Is there any property to put input field below the label when screen size is small?

Comment: Oops, just add it to the input

Comment: Please check my image so you can better understand my problem. Thanks

Comment: I still don't really understand, you want the input under the label, this does that, doesn't it?

Comment: even I don't understand the problem. But this is not working in my case.

Comment: Can you post a link to the site, or your relevant html and css, or a jsfiddle?

Comment: I tried all the things but still Input Filed not placing below the label.

Comment: Can you post a link to the website?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<label>this is lable</label>
<div class="text">
    <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
label{
    float:left;
}
.text{
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0 0 0 20px;
}
.text input{
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:5px 15px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    label{
        display:block;
    }
    .text{
        clear:both;
        padding:0;
    }
}
```

[*Demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/khanshaban/whm30bv5/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: label{

    float:left;

}
.text{
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0 0 0 20px;
}
.text input{
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:5px 15px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    label{
        display:block;
    }
    .text{
        clear:both;
        padding:0;
    }
}

Comment: <label>this is lable</label><div class="text"><input type="text"></div>

Comment: Check my edit. Answer in this format. There is an option to edit answer, you should include code there instead in comments. :)

Comment: Please check my image so you can better understand my problem. Thanks

Comment: Hey it works in chrome but its not working in safari. Is there any different syntax for safari?